# How can I add dimension constraint to psql table?

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I'm creating a geoserver layer dynamically and I'd like to add some contraints to it. The constraint I'd like `CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_geom3 CHECK (st_ndims(geom) = 3)`
I've tried to add it with

```
GSFeatureDimensionInfoEncoder dim3 = new GSFeatureDimensionInfoEncoder("ELE");
featureTypeEncoder.setMetadataDimension("elevation",dim3);
```

This does not affect the result at all. How can I add it?

**EDIT**

I'm creating the layer with `GSAttributeEndcoder`

```
GSAttributeEncoder attribute = new GSAttributeEncoder();
        attribute.setAttribute(FeatureTypeAttribute.name, "geom");
        attribute.setAttribute(FeatureTypeAttribute.minOccurs, String.valueOf(0));
        attribute.setAttribute(FeatureTypeAttribute.maxOccurs, String.valueOf(1));
        attribute.setAttribute(FeatureTypeAttribute.nillable, String.valueOf(true));
        attribute.setAttribute(FeatureTypeAttribute.binding, "com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry");
        featureTypeEncoder.setAttribute(attribute);
```

And publishing it with

```
GeoserverRestPublisher p = new GeoserverRestPublisher(stuff);
p.publishDBLayer(username, username, featureTypeEncoder, layerEncoder);
```

Comment: You are probably using geoserver-manager. Can you please add it in the question and better explain, how exactly do you create the layer? I don't think that the class GSFeatureDimensionInfoEncoder should be used directly

Comment: @TommasoDiBucchianico I'm creating the layer with `GSAttributeEndcoder`